# Rotate Labels in d3 sunburst v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I try to use the d3 v4 sunburst to visulize some data from a .json
I can display the sunburst diagramm with the labels i want, but the labels on the left side are upside down.
I tried various methode, which i found on so or other sources but nothing works for me.

Heres my coding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
stroke: #fff;
}

text {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="data.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script language="javascript">

var width = 1200,
height = 1000,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, radius]);

var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);



var partition = d3.partition();

var arc = d3.arc()
.startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, 
 x(d.x0))); })
.endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x1))); 
 })
.innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y0)); })
.outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y1)); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

 root = d3.hierarchy(root);
root.sum(function(d) { return d.size; });
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(partition(root).descendants())
    .enter().append("g").attr("class", "node");

 path = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : 
 d.parent).data.name); })
  .on("click", click);

text = svg.selectAll(".node")
   .append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
         return  "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; 
      })

      .attr("x", function(d) { 
         return y(d.y0); 
      })
      .attr("dx", "6") // margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .text(function(d) { 
          return d.data.name === "root" ? "" : d.data.name
      });


  function click(d) {
  //Hide text while Sunburst transitions
  text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);

  svg.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .tween("scale", function() {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x0, d.x1]),
        yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y0, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y0 ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); };
   })
  .selectAll("path")
  .attrTween("d", function(d) { return function() { return arc(d); }; })
  .on("end", function(e, i) {
      // Check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible 
      // angle span given in d:
      if (e.x0 >= d.x0 && e.x0 < d.x1) {
          // get a selection of the associated text element
          var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
          // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
          arcText.transition().duration(750)
              .attr("opacity", 1)

              .attr("transform", function() { return "rotate(" + 
  computeTextRotation(e) + ")" })
              .attr("x", function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
              .text(function(d) { 
                  return d.data.name === "root" ? "" : d.data.name
              });
      }
  });
  }

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

 // Interpolate the scales!
 function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
  yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
  yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
 return i
    ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
    : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return 
 arc(d); };
  };
 }

 function computeTextRotation(d) {
  var angle = (x((d.x0 + d.x1)/2) - Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180;
  return (angle >  90 || angle < 270) ?  angle : 180 + angle ;

  }



  </script>
```

and this is the data.json:

```
var root={
"id":"00000001", "name": "",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000003", "name":"#",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000003", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000002", "name":"Nov","size":           12608.00},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000010", "name":"A",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000010", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000003", "name":"Dez","size":          119215.80},
{
"id":"00000004", "name":"Jul","size":            5000.00},
{
"id":"00000005", "name":"Jun","size":           45536.00},
{
"id":"00000006", "name":"Mai","size":           18500.00},
{
"id":"00000007", "name":"Nov","size":           20107.31},
{
"id":"00000008", "name":"Okt","size":           70303.00},
{
"id":"00000009", "name":"Sep","size":           11240.00},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000018", "name":"DIR",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000018", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000010", "name":"Aug","size":          705110.07},
{
"id":"00000011", "name":"Dez","size":          667101.28},
{
"id":"00000012", "name":"Jul","size":          684326.04},
{
"id":"00000013", "name":"Jun","size":          975615.11},
{
"id":"00000014", "name":"Mai","size":          625832.83},
{
"id":"00000015", "name":"Nov","size":          488444.60},
{
"id":"00000016", "name":"Okt","size":          578924.89},
{
"id":"00000017", "name":"Sep","size":          755968.14},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000020", "name":"EU",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000020", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000018", "name":"Nov","size":          505400.00},
{
"id":"00000019", "name":"Sep","size":          505400.00},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000028", "name":"NAT",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000028", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000020", "name":"Aug","size":         1882688.00},
{
"id":"00000021", "name":"Dez","size":          268861.33},
{
"id":"00000022", "name":"Jul","size":         1174708.67},
{
"id":"00000023", "name":"Jun","size":         3860969.90},
{
"id":"00000024", "name":"Mai","size":          917468.75},
{
"id":"00000025", "name":"Nov","size":         2233213.25},
{
"id":"00000026", "name":"Okt","size":         2340277.41},
{
"id":"00000027", "name":"Sep","size":         1667464.09},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000036", "name":"X",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000036", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000028", "name":"Aug","size":          249939.37},
{
"id":"00000029", "name":"Dez","size":          289363.70},
{
"id":"00000030", "name":"Jul","size":           98847.32},
{
"id":"00000031", "name":"Jun9","size":            7799.00},
{
"id":"00000032", "name":"Mai","size":           19520.00},
{
"id":"00000033", "name":"Nov","size":         1177309.62},
{
"id":"00000034", "name":"Okt","size":          224970.85},
{
"id":"00000035", "name":"Sep","size":          167309.57},
] },
] },
] }
```

This is how it looks like at the moment
 [image: ]]

as you can see the left side is upside down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to rotate by an additional 180° text labels which have an angle between 90° and 270° (left part of the graph).

Here is the updated demo:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
stroke: #fff;
}

text {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

var root={
"id":"00000001", "name": "",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000003", "name":"#",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000003", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000002", "name":"Nov","size":           12608.00},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000010", "name":"A",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000010", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000003", "name":"Dez","size":          119215.80},
{
"id":"00000004", "name":"Jul","size":            5000.00},
{
"id":"00000005", "name":"Jun","size":           45536.00},
{
"id":"00000006", "name":"Mai","size":           18500.00},
{
"id":"00000007", "name":"Nov","size":           20107.31},
{
"id":"00000008", "name":"Okt","size":           70303.00},
{
"id":"00000009", "name":"Sep","size":           11240.00},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000018", "name":"DIR",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000018", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000010", "name":"Aug","size":          705110.07},
{
"id":"00000011", "name":"Dez","size":          667101.28},
{
"id":"00000012", "name":"Jul","size":          684326.04},
{
"id":"00000013", "name":"Jun","size":          975615.11},
{
"id":"00000014", "name":"Mai","size":          625832.83},
{
"id":"00000015", "name":"Nov","size":          488444.60},
{
"id":"00000016", "name":"Okt","size":          578924.89},
{
"id":"00000017", "name":"Sep","size":          755968.14},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000020", "name":"EU",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000020", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000018", "name":"Nov","size":          505400.00},
{
"id":"00000019", "name":"Sep","size":          505400.00},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000028", "name":"NAT",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000028", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000020", "name":"Aug","size":         1882688.00},
{
"id":"00000021", "name":"Dez","size":          268861.33},
{
"id":"00000022", "name":"Jul","size":         1174708.67},
{
"id":"00000023", "name":"Jun","size":         3860969.90},
{
"id":"00000024", "name":"Mai","size":          917468.75},
{
"id":"00000025", "name":"Nov","size":         2233213.25},
{
"id":"00000026", "name":"Okt","size":         2340277.41},
{
"id":"00000027", "name":"Sep","size":         1667464.09},
] },
] },
{
"id":"00000036", "name":"X",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000036", "name":"2017",
"children": [
{
"id":"00000028", "name":"Aug","size":          249939.37},
{
"id":"00000029", "name":"Dez","size":          289363.70},
{
"id":"00000030", "name":"Jul","size":           98847.32},
{
"id":"00000031", "name":"Jun9","size":            7799.00},
{
"id":"00000032", "name":"Mai","size":           19520.00},
{
"id":"00000033", "name":"Nov","size":         1177309.62},
{
"id":"00000034", "name":"Okt","size":          224970.85},
{
"id":"00000035", "name":"Sep","size":          167309.57},
] },
] },
] }

var width = 1200,
height = 1000,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, radius]);

var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var partition = d3.partition();

var arc = d3.arc()
.startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, 
 x(d.x0))); })
.endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x1))); 
 })
.innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y0)); })
.outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y1)); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

 root = d3.hierarchy(root);
root.sum(function(d) { return d.size; });
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(partition(root).descendants())
    .enter().append("g").attr("class", "node");

 path = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : 
 d.parent).data.name); })
  .on("click", click);

text = svg.selectAll(".node")
   .append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
         var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
         var translation = y(d.y0);
         if (rotation > 90 && rotation < 270) {
           rotation = rotation + 180;
           translation = -translation - 13;
         }
         return (
           "rotate(" + rotation + ")" +
           "translate(" + translation + ",0)"
         );
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
        return (rotation > 90 && rotation < 270) ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .attr("dx", function(d) {
        var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
        return (rotation > 90 && rotation < 270) ? -6 : 6;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .text(function(d) { 
          return d.data.name === "root" ? "" : d.data.name
      });


  function click(d) {
  //Hide text while Sunburst transitions
  text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);

  svg.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .tween("scale", function() {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x0, d.x1]),
        yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y0, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y0 ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); };
   })
  .selectAll("path")
  .attrTween("d", function(d) { return function() { return arc(d); }; })
  .on("end", function(e, i) {
      // Check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible 
      // angle span given in d:
      if (e.x0 >= d.x0 && e.x0 < d.x1) {
          // get a selection of the associated text element
          var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
          // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
          arcText.transition().duration(750)
              .attr("opacity", 1)

              .attr("transform", function() { return "rotate(" + 
  computeTextRotation(e) + ")" })
              .attr("x", function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
              .text(function(d) { 
                  return d.data.name === "root" ? "" : d.data.name
              });
      }
  });
  }

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

 // Interpolate the scales!
 function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
  yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
  yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
 return i
    ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
    : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return 
 arc(d); };
  };
 }

 function computeTextRotation(d) {
  var angle = (x((d.x0 + d.x1)/2) - Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180;
  return (angle >  90 || angle < 270) ?  angle : 180 + angle ;

  }

  </script>
```

Let's go step by step:

First we'll apply this conditional additional rotation:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
  var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
  if (rotation > 90 && rotation < 270)
    rotation = rotation + 180;
  return "rotate(" + rotation + ")";
})
```

But then all labels are on the right part of the graph...

This means we then have to reverse the translation for left labels:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
  var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
  var translation = y(d.y0);
  if (rotation > 90 && rotation < 270) {
    rotation = rotation + 180;
    translation = -translation;
  }
  return (
    "rotate(" + rotation + ")" +
    "translate(" + translation + ",0)"
  );
})
```

Here I've prefered to perform the `translate` using the `transform` operator rather than the `x` attribute the `text` element.

But then the text is not exactly at the right spot in its shape...

This can be fixed by modifying the `text-anchor` of labels for left elements to be at the end of the text. We can do this by using this attribute:

```
.attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
  var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
  return (rotation > 90 && rotation < 270) ? "end" : "start";
})
```

And finally, it's still not perfect since we'd like the same margin for labels on the left than on the right. We can thus adjust our translation for left items:

```
.attr("dx", function(d) {
  var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
  return (rotation > 90 && rotation < 270) ? -6 : 6;
})
```

*You can replicate this method to adapt the `click` function as well.*