# d3.partition sunbursts: rotating text and other glitches

Tags: d3.js, hierarchy, partition

d3.hierarchy generally and d3.partition in particular are some of my
favorite tools out of that great library.  But I'm applying them to
radial "sunburst" viz for the first time, and seem to be missing some
important bits.

Attached below is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
example generating this sunburst, to illustrate my main questions:
[image: sample sunburst]

### Rotating text

Rotating text labels beyond 180 degrees is a common issue;
   cf. [this recent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252652/rotate-labels-in-d3-sunburst-v4)

Following
[@mbostock's own example](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-sunburst)
has this transform code:

```
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                    const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
                    const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2;
                    return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
                    })
```

but using this `translate()` in the transform throws the text far off
the chart?

So the code below does a rotation based on the same average of
inner/outer arc radii, and places the labels right-side (angles < 180)
the same way, except that it uses a `text-anchor` alignment variation
to align both depths' labels with respect to the same common circle.

- 1 I've had to modify the radius by a hacked factor of `1.22` to nudge
  the (right-side) labels close to the line; **why**?
- 2 This works great for all labels except the root's, which I want
  centered; **how can I do that?**
- 3 But the new left-side (> 180 degrees) labels are not well-placed,
  and I've needed to add a depth-specific `hackRatio` in order to
  moderate the translation to even get them this close; **why?**
- 4 A deeper problem is to figure out how to use the same 
  `text-anchor` alignment trick used for the other labels?  I want to do the rotation "in place"
  *prior to* alignment being applied; **how can I do that?**

### How is d3.hierarchy.sum() supposed to work?

The labels also include the `freq` attribute in parentheses. The `yearHier` data
provides this attribute only for data *leaves*.  My impression from
the [d3.hierarchy.sum()](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#node_sum)
and [d3.partition](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#partition) doc
was that the call to `sum()` on the root would calculate the sums for
non-leaves ("... for this node and each descendant in post-order traversal"); **why are these frequencies zero?**

So as an alternative, I tried using the `yearHierFreq` data which incudes total frequencies for root and each year.  But using it, d3.partition allocates only only two thirds of the years' arcs, and only half of the months' arcs within each year; see rendering below.  It's as if the interior nodes' `freq` is being double counted; **why**?

[image: using yearHierFreq data with all freq provided]

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>

var ColorNames = ["Blue", "Gray", "Purple", "Fuchsia", "Aqua", "Maroon", "Olive", "Yellow", "Teal", "Navy", "Green", "Silver", "Red", "Lime"];

// following after http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

var width = 900;
var height = 900;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 * 0.7;

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius]);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d)  { return d.x0; })
    .endAngle(function(d)    { return d.x1; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y0); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y1); });

function createSunburst(json) {

 vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // Turn the data into a d3 hierarchy and calculate the sums.
  var root = d3.hierarchy(json)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.freq; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.name - a.name; });

  var partition = d3.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius]);

  var nodes = partition(root).descendants();

   var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d,i) { return ColorNames[i % 14]; })
      .style("opacity", 1);

    var texts = vis.selectAll("text")
        .data(nodes)
.enter().append("text")

/*      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            // https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-sunburst
                        const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
                        const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2;
                        return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
                        })           
*/
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            var deg;
            if (d.depth==0) {
                deg = 90;
            } else {
                deg = 180 / Math.PI * (d.x0 +d.x1) / 2;
            }
            var trans = `rotate(${deg-90})`;
            if (deg > 180) { 
                var hackRatio = (d.depth == 0) ? 160 : 130;
                var yavg = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 / hackRatio;
                trans += ` translate(${yavg},0) rotate(180)`; 
            }
            return trans})

        .attr("x", radius / 1.22 )
        .text(function(d) {return  `${d.data.name} (${d.data.freq})`;})

        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
            var alignVec = ["center","end","start"];
            return alignVec[d.depth];})
 };

var yearHier = {"freq": 0, "name": "AllYears", "children": [{"freq": 0, "name": "2017", "children": [{"freq": 5, "name": "January", "children": []}, {"freq": 17, "name": "February", "children": []}, {"freq": 16, "name": "March", "children": []}, {"freq": 2, "name": "April", "children": []}, {"freq": 18, "name": "May", "children": []}, {"freq": 14, "name": "June", "children": []}, {"freq": 17, "name": "July", "children": []}, {"freq": 2, "name": "August", "children": []}, {"freq": 10, "name": "September", "children": []}, {"freq": 6, "name": "October", "children": []}, {"freq": 10, "name": "November", "children": []}, {"freq": 17, "name": "December", "children": []}]}, {"freq": 0, "name": "2018", "children": [{"freq": 14, "name": "January", "children": []}, {"freq": 6, "name": "February", "children": []}, {"freq": 13, "name": "March", "children": []}, {"freq": 15, "name": "April", "children": []}, {"freq": 15, "name": "May", "children": []}, {"freq": 4, "name": "June", "children": []}, {"freq": 7, "name": "July", "children": []}, {"freq": 12, "name": "August", "children": []}, {"freq": 17, "name": "September", "children": []}, {"freq": 8, "name": "October", "children": []}, {"freq": 10, "name": "November", "children": []}, {"freq": 12, "name": "December", "children": []}]}, {"freq": 0, "name": "2019", "children": [{"freq": 10, "name": "January", "children": []}, {"freq": 12, "name": "February", "children": []}, {"freq": 15, "name": "March", "children": []}, {"freq": 6, "name": "April", "children": []}, {"freq": 14, "name": "May", "children": []}, {"freq": 3, "name": "June", "children": []}, {"freq": 6, "name": "July", "children": []}, {"freq": 9, "name": "August", "children": []}, {"freq": 18, "name": "September", "children": []}, {"freq": 4, "name": "October", "children": []}, {"freq": 8, "name": "November", "children": []}, {"freq": 16, "name": "December", "children": []}]}]}

var yearHierFreq = {"freq": 355, "name": "AllMonths", "children": [{"freq": 83, "name": "2017", "children": [{"freq": 4, "name": "January", "children": []}, {"freq": 7, "name": "February", "children": []}, {"freq": 4, "name": "March", "children": []}, {"freq": 11, "name": "April", "children": []}, {"freq": 16, "name": "May", "children": []}, {"freq": 8, "name": "June", "children": []}, {"freq": 5, "name": "July", "children": []}, {"freq": 3, "name": "August", "children": []}, {"freq": 10, "name": "September", "children": []}, {"freq": 3, "name": "October", "children": []}, {"freq": 2, "name": "November", "children": []}, {"freq": 10, "name": "December", "children": []}]}, {"freq": 156, "name": "2018", "children": [{"freq": 14, "name": "January", "children": []}, {"freq": 8, "name": "February", "children": []}, {"freq": 12, "name": "March", "children": []}, {"freq": 10, "name": "April", "children": []}, {"freq": 16, "name": "May", "children": []}, {"freq": 17, "name": "June", "children": []}, {"freq": 19, "name": "July", "children": []}, {"freq": 14, "name": "August", "children": []}, {"freq": 4, "name": "September", "children": []}, {"freq": 17, "name": "October", "children": []}, {"freq": 19, "name": "November", "children": []}, {"freq": 6, "name": "December", "children": []}]}, {"freq": 116, "name": "2019", "children": [{"freq": 4, "name": "January", "children": []}, {"freq": 15, "name": "February", "children": []}, {"freq": 12, "name": "March", "children": []}, {"freq": 8, "name": "April", "children": []}, {"freq": 3, "name": "May", "children": []}, {"freq": 5, "name": "June", "children": []}, {"freq": 13, "name": "July", "children": []}, {"freq": 19, "name": "August", "children": []}, {"freq": 12, "name": "September", "children": []}, {"freq": 11, "name": "October", "children": []}, {"freq": 5, "name": "November", "children": []}, {"freq": 9, "name": "December", "children": []}]}]}

createSunburst(yearHier);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "700px");
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the following result

[image]

with this code

```
var radiusSeparation = 5;

var texts = vis.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (d.depth == 0) return null;
        d.deg = 180 / Math.PI * (d.x0 + d.x1) * 0.5;
        var translate = d.depth == 1 ? Math.sqrt(d.y1)-radiusSeparation : Math.sqrt(d.y0)+radiusSeparation;
        var trans = `rotate(${(d.deg-90).toFixed(2)}) translate(${translate.toFixed(2)},0)`;
        if (d.deg > 180) {
            trans += ` rotate(180)`;
        }
        return trans;
    })
    .text( d => `${d.data.name} (${d.value})` )
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        if (d.depth == 0) return "middle";
        if (d.depth == 1) return d.deg < 180 ? "end" : "start";
        return d.deg < 180 ? "start" : "end";
    })
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
```

- use the radius of your arcs to position the text. Use a small separation distance so the text does not touch the arcs
- store the `deg` value in the datum so you can use it for the text anchor
- switch text-anchor based on deg value
- treat depth=0 as special in all cases
- vertical align the text to the middle with `dominant-baseline`
- d3.hierarchy.sum() stores the result in `d.value`, so use this in the text

Comment: lovely!  the best (OK, only) bounty points i've ever spent.  thank you @rioV8.